# Trying to get image URL upon upload in WP Forms

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am using WP Forms to create a "customizer" using SVGs and a custom JS file to grab the values the user has made to create a "jersey" design. I am trying now to get the custom logo. However it seems upon first attempt I get a JSON error as WPForms front end give the image upload a JSON obj. After you upload it a second time, it works like a charm to give me the url so I can display it in the logo area.

Any ideas on how to get the url on first go and not have the JSON error would be great.

Here is the link to the site:

https://sublimatedhockeyjerseys.com/jersey-customizer/

Here is the error:

VM168:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at HTMLDivElement.

Here is my code:

`logoObj.addEventListener('change', function() { console.log(document.getElementById('wpforms-59-field_39')); console.log(document.getElementById('wpforms-59-field_39').value);  var parsed = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('wpforms-59-field_39').value)[0].url; console.log(parsed); });`

Comment: You're doing `[0]`.  Are you completely sure that element returns a list, even on the very first use?

Comment: So it doesn't return anything on first upload when the code fire. However, after its fully uploaded it works. Or whenever its uploaded a second or 3rd or anytime after it works.

Comment: Well, that gives you something to check for, anyway.